# Why does C++ define the norm as the Euclidean norm squared?

Tags: c++, math

This may sound like a bit of a rhetorical question, but I ask it here for two reasons:

1. It took me a while to figure out what C++ std::norm() was doing differently from [MATLAB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB)/[Octave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Octave), so others may stumble upon it here.
2. I find it odd to define the `norm()` function as being something different (though closely related) to what is generally considered to be the norm (or L2-norm, or Euclidean norm, etc., etc.)

Specifically the C++ standard library defines `norm()` for complex numbers to be the square of the modulus (or absolute value), where the modulus is sqrt(a^2 + b^2) when the complex number is in the form a + i*b.

This goes against my understanding of the norm, which when specified as the Euclidean norm (which corresponds to the modulus used here), is the square root of the sum of squares. I'll reference [Mathworld's definition of the complex modulus](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexModulus.html).

Is this something others have run into? I found it as a result of porting some signal processing code from Octave to C++, and the only other place I found reference to this difference was on the GCC mailing list.

Comment: Discussion on GCC mailing list here: http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2001-08/msg01129.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The C++ usage of the word "norm" is rather confusing, since most people have only ever come across norms in the context of vector spaces.  If you view the complex numbers as a vector space over the reals, this is definitely not a norm.  In fairness to C++, the std::norm( ) function does compute the so-called [Field Norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_norm) from the complex numbers to the reals.

Fortunately, there is the std::abs( ) function, which does what you want.

Comment: Ah, I was not aware of the field norm - that certainly makes sense, or at least provides a plausible explanation of why they chose to define norm() this way.

Comment: Probably it was just a coincidence.

Comment: I recall Mathworld stating that the usage of "norm" when talking about complexs or complex-like numbers is ambiguous. The field norm has some advantages  as what is pointed by Kevin Reid below, and also the fact that it is closed in the number field - the C++ norm of an "integer complex" is an integer, so it is possible to optimize with integer-only ops.

Answer (score 6):

Incidentally, the Euclidean norm squared can be useful as an optimization, especially in game physics; if you want to *compare* magnitudes/distances, or for any other reason don't need **linearity**, then you can work with the squared distances rather than the actual distances, and avoid computing square roots.

```
norm(v1) < norm(v2)         instead of   abs(v1) < abs(v2)
norm(v) < CONSTANT_SQUARED  instead of   abs(v) < CONSTANT
```

(using the fact that abs() is magnitude as mentioned in another answer)